# filemaker.php next/previous buttons on record detail page

Tags: php, filemaker

I'm using filemaker server 10 and the filemaker.php API.
on the record detail page, I'd like a "next" and "previous" button to allow browsing the next/previous buttons easily (without having to go back to the list view).

is this possible and how?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In browserecord.php need to define the record id for the next next record-

```
   $recid = $cgi->get('-recid'); \\ exists
$recnxt = ($cgi->get('-recid')+1);  \\added  for next record
```

Then you can place anywhere:

```
<a href='<?php echo "browserecord.php?-action=browse&amp;-recid=$recnxt";?>'>Next record</a>
```

This does not check that the next record exists of course.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easier way to do the above (you don't need to define recnxt):

```
<a href=browserecord.php?-action=browse&amp;-recid=<?php echo ($recid + 1) ;?>>Next record</a>
```

The problem with these solutions is they only go to the record created after the current one, and only if it has not been deleted. If your list is the result of a search or records have been sorted the next  record in the list won't be the 'recid+1', so this is of very limited use.